# Change mongo document's id via spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

Is there a way to modify the id of all documents in a Mongo collection with spring mongo?

Trying this in many ways I got error messages like:

```
the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id
```

or

```
Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=16837, message='The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: "xyz"} to {_id: "zxy"}.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to update the _id field. But you can always set a brand new _id to an existing doc and remove the older _id.

Comment: when I tried to use BasicDBObject's replaceOne method to replace the id, it gives me the second error. Or it's not what you meant by set a new _id and remove the older?

Comment: I dont have access to the mongo driver now, but this is what I was hinting at (not tested) :

BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1234));
someCollection.update(someSearchQuery, set);
Meanwhile, get the older _id before this and remove it after you set the new one.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130161/how-to-update-the-id-field-in-a-mongodb-document